# Append letter before previous name in folder. (Rename)

Tags: command-line, 16.10, rename, batch-rename

I have multiple folders and each one have around 175 files in it. 
file names are like

```
1.wav
2.wav
3.wav
......
175.wav
```

I have to rename them as

```
A1.wav
A2.wav
A3.wav
......
A175.wav
```

In other words I have to append Letters in previous file names.

I am wondering if there is a easy way to do this.

Ubuntu Version is 16.10

Answer (score 3):

User `prename` command:

```
$ prename -nv 's/^(.*)$/A$1/' *.wav                    
1.wav renamed as A1.wav
2.wav renamed as A2.wav
3.wav renamed as A3.wav
```

The way this reads is simple:

- `*.wav` allows the shell to expand the wild card to list of all files that end with `.wav`. When the shell runs the full command, the computer will see `prename -nv 's/^(.*)$/A$1/' 1.wav 2.wav 3.wav` and so on as the actual command.
- The `'s/^(.*)$/A$1/'` is actually is `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT` regular expression with grouping `(.*)`, which allows us to group the whole name of the file from beginning `^` to end `$` and refer to it as `$1`.

Note that `-nv` switches are for verbose `-v` and dry-run `-n`. If you're happy with the test run, remove `-n` to apply actual renaming.

Comment: What if I have to rename it as 1A.wav and 2A.wav etc. 
I tried with. " prename -nv 's/^(.*)$/$1A/' *.wav  "  it renames like it 1.wavA and 2.wavA

Comment: @AdnanAli  Yes, because `^(.*)` makes the whole name to be treated as `$1`. So you're literally sticking A at the end of whole name. What you want to do is use extra grouping, make `$1` be everything before `.wav` and make `.wav` be `$2`. Like this:  `prename -nv 's/^(.*)(.wav)$/$1A$2/' *.wav`  So here first `(.*)` will be `$1` and is everything before `.wav`. The second  group `(.wav)`is `$2`

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways, my own choice would be a 'for' loop:

```
for f in *.wav ; do mv "$f" "A$f" ; done
```

This is simple and easily modified for other needs...

Answer (score 2):

Using `rename`:

```
rename 's/([0-9]+).wav/A\1.wav/' *.wav
```

- `s/SEARCH-FOR/REPLACE-WITH/  within-this-files`
- `([0-9]+)` holds the number section then we can use it again using `\1`.
- `A\1.wav`: `A` + (numberic section) + `.wav`